# Why is there no content when add a new tab in jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Firs of all, I create a tab with the code below:

```
<div id="statsTabs" style="width:100%; height:100%">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#f-campaign"><span>广告系列</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#f-adgroup"><span>广告组</span></a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div id="f-campaign">...</div>
<div id="f-adgroup">...</div>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#statsTabs").tabs();
   });
</script>
```

every thing work well, but when I try the code below, I get some problems:

```
$("#statsTabs").tabs( "remove" , 0);
$("#statsTabs").tabs("add", '#f-campaign', "广告系列" , 0);
```

A new tab with the tag "广告系列" appears but there is no content in it, why? Since the first code segment gets the content of #f-campaign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this: `$("#statsTabs").tabs( "remove" , 0);`
remove the the `li` and the associated `div` as well, so when you add the tab again it has no content, as expected.

Comment: So there is a way to remove the tab but keep the associated div? Because I need it later.

Comment: If disabling it would be enough for you, you may want to read [this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#method-disable) (documentation of the jquery ui tabs, there is a method called disabled that can disable a tab given its indes)

Comment: Yes, I may disable it even though it is not beautiful.

Comment: It's possible to remove the tab  and maintain the data you need but, as far as I can tell, it isn't possible to do that with just the methods set given by jquery ui tabs. You may have to write your own code to manage the required behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling the Remove function it removes the tab, and the content.

This is the reason that you just can't add it again. You need to build it again to do this.

I made a JS fiddle with a `console.log()` that demonstrates this: http://jsfiddle.net/Allan/2YcBh/

You can avoid this by using the callback function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#statsTabs").tabs({
       remove: function(event, ui) {
        // Back up the content here, or simply move the tab so that you can add it again later.
       }
    });
    $('input').click(function() {
        $("#statsTabs").tabs( "remove" , 0);
        console.log($('#f-campaign'));
        $("#statsTabs").tabs("add", '#f-campaign', "广告系列" , 0);
    });
});​
```

Comment: Sorry, I make a mistake when asking the question above and the original code is <div id="f-adgroup">...</div>. My question is that there is no content in the tab added.

Comment: You also need to have the two tabs in the id="statsTabs" div, do you have this?

Comment: what he meant is that you need to put those two tabs inside the 'statsTabs' div

Comment: Yes, I think I put  those two tabs inside the 'statsTabs' div and that's why the code segment works before I removing and adding a tab.

Comment: They need to be within the div or the Tabs won't work. Your problem is that when you call the remove command you delete the tab, and it's content. You then have no way of adding it again.